# Warning message: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a really simple script in R but I keep having this message : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I've try ifelse, it doesn't work.

Here's my script:

```
a <- sample(0:1, replace=TRUE, size=10084)
presence <- 0
for (i in 10084) {
  presence[i] = a
}
```

If someone knows a solution, please let me know :)

Comment: hmmm why not you just put presence <- sample(0:1, replace=TRUE, size=10084)

Comment: in any case, you got to do presence <- vector("numeric",10084)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, in the script, `presence` is of length 1 and 'a' 10084 and the assignment is not right as well as the `for(i in 10084)` because 10084 is a single value

```
presence <- numeric(length(a))
for(i in seq_along(a)) presence[i] <- a[i]
```

But, it can be simply created by assigning

```
presence <- a
```

Comment: I read it as a is a vector and presence is also a vector simply equal to a: `presence <- a`

Comment: @SteveM yes, the `presence <-a` is mentioned in my post

Answer (score 0):

```
presence <- matrix(NA, 1, 10)
presence
for (i in 1:10) {
  presence[,] = a
}
presence
```

[image: output]